# Postgres stored procedure passing variadic parameter and using it to query uuids

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I am currently trying to write a stored procedure in postgres. What I want to do is pass uuid's to the procedure and have it delete everything not in the array of uuids for those tables.

I'm getting an error:

> operator does not exist: uuid = text

Here is my stored procedure

```
create or replace procedure deleting_projects_with_exemptions(
    variadic project_ids uuid[]
)
language plpgsql
as $$
begin
    -- Delete tables
    delete from user_project where not (project_id = any (project_ids));
end;
$$;
```

I have validated that the `projects` table is using `uuid` as the column type and also the `user_project` table's `project_id` is a uuid with a foreign key reference to the `projects` table.

I'm not sure why it's saying I have a text to uuid comparison when I don't.

I am calling the function like the following:

`call deleting_projects_with_exemptions('4b589296-b5a3-48ab-94c4-f85624cd8e14');`

I'm sure im just not understanding part of the variadic type but the error isnt helping resolve the issue.

I'm trying to get the stored procedure to accepted the array of project uuids to delete the other records that are not in that array.

Comment: Works just fine in v15, see [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/47iX8EF8). What version are you running. Also what is the complete error message you are getting and several lines of code surrounding the call. Answer with update to yiur question not with a comment.

Comment: You do have a *...text to uuid comparison...* comparison as `project_id = any (project_ids)` is equivalent to `project_id = <each_array_element>` in turn. See [ANY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#id-1.5.8.30.16). You might try an explicit cast: `call deleting_projects_with_exemptions('4b589296-b5a3-48ab-94c4-f85624cd8e14'::uuid);`

Comment: I cannot replicate in Postgres 14.